# Why did Angular JS Team choose protractor as name for its end to end testing tool.?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Is there  any reason for choosing the name as  "protractor" for angular js end to end testing tool.

Comment: Because a protractor is a tool used to measure *angles*, and protractor is used to test *angular* applications, which make it a logical and funny name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular (Angle)--> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Angular_dia_formula.JPG and you use a Protractor to measure an angle---> http://nc5thgrademath.weebly.com/uploads/4/5/0/5/4505897/__4602089.gif?349

[Official answer endorsed](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2476) by Julie